# Range calculation by row in R

Tags: r, range, tibble

I have a 4x4 tibble, and I'm practicing various dplyr functions on it.

I would like to calculate the range of each row, and display the range of that row as a single number in a new column.

Here is my code:

```
my_tibble <- data.frame(col1 = c(1:5), col2 = c(6:10), col3 = c(11:15), col4 = c(16:20))
my_tibble <- as_tibble(my_tibble)
```

I attempted a for loop to solve this problem but can't understand how the for loop interacts with the subsetted tibble data:

```
for (rows in 1:4)
  my_range <- max(my_tibble[rows, 1:4]) - min(my_tibble[rows, 1:4])
```

In summary, I would like as many ways possible to display the max-min (i.e. range) in a new column in the tibble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In base R, you could use `diff` with `range` in an `apply` statement:

```
my_tibble$rngdiff <- apply(my_tibble, 1, function(x) diff(range(x)))
```

`diff(range(x))` finds the range of an input and take the difference. The `apply` function with index set to `1` performs the function across each row. Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 5
   col1  col2  col3  col4  rngdiff
  <int> <int> <int> <int>    <int>
1     1     6    11    16       15
2     2     7    12    17       15
3     3     8    13    18       15
4     4     9    14    19       15
5     5    10    15    20       15
```

Your proposed `for` loop doesn't work for two primary reasons: (1) you are not indexing, `my_range` so it overwrites every iteration and (2) your `rows` index does not cover the total number of rows (there are 5). A corrected `for` loop statement could be:

```
my_tibble$diffloop <- NA
for(rows in seq_len(nrow(my_tibble))){
  my_tibble$diffloop[rows] <- max(my_tibble[rows, 1:4]) - min(my_tibble[rows, 1:4])
  # or
  # my_tibble$diffloop[rows] <- diff(range(my_tibble[rows, 1:4]))
}
```

(though for the record I dont think you should use `for` loops here)

Answer (score 4):

Using `rowwise` can let you use `min` and `max` directly:

```
library(tidyverse)

my_tibble %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(range = max(c_across(col1:col4)) - min(c_across(col1:col4)))

# A tibble: 5 × 5
# Rowwise: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4 range
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     6    11    16    15
2     2     7    12    17    15
3     3     8    13    18    15
4     4     9    14    19    15
5     5    10    15    20    15
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `pmax/pmin`

```
my_tibble$range <- do.call(`-`, lapply(c(pmax, pmin), \(f) do.call(f, my_tibble)))
```

gives

```
> my_tibble
# A tibble: 5 × 5
   col1  col2  col3  col4 range
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     6    11    16    15
2     2     7    12    17    15
3     3     8    13    18    15
4     4     9    14    19    15
5     5    10    15    20    15
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `pmax/pmin`

```
library(dplyr)
 my_tibble %>% 
  mutate(range = do.call(pmax, pick(everything())) - 
   do.call(pmin, pick(everything())))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 5
   col1  col2  col3  col4 range
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     6    11    16    15
2     2     7    12    17    15
3     3     8    13    18    15
4     4     9    14    19    15
5     5    10    15    20    15
```